# D3 Json to Hardcoded variables

Tags: d3.js

I want to turn the fetching of data from JSON to a hardcoded variable. This is the link to the d3 treemap chart: [Zoomable Treemap Template](http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022).

Comment: could you post any code you may have written up to this point.

Comment: I have not started anything yet I am basing on the template on the link. I am just thinking of how can I use hard coded data instead of a json

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to put JSON data into a variable, then you would represent this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Asia",
    "values": [
    {
      "key": "India",
      "value": 1236670000
    },
    {
      "key": "China",
      "value": 1361170000
    }]
  },
  {
    "key": "Africa",
    "values": [
    {
      "key": "Nigeria",
      "value": 173615000
    },
    {
      "key": "Egypt",
      "value": 83661000
    }]
  }
]
```

like this:

```
var x = [
  {
    "key": "Asia",
    "values": [
    {
      "key": "India",
      "value": 1236670000
    },
    {
      "key": "China",
      "value": 1361170000
    }]
  },
  {
    "key": "Africa",
    "values": [
    {
      "key": "Nigeria",
      "value": 173615000
    },
    {
      "key": "Egypt",
      "value": 83661000
    }]
  }
];
```

Comment: How can I call the variable to the d3